# How can I search for the ownerID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I just have a small task to do

I want that when I create a post that the user is read from my token

create Function:

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.token;
  const users = await User.findOne({ userID: user });
  const { forumName, forumDescription } = req.body;
  const errors = [];
  if (!forumName) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please Write a Title." });
  }
  if (!forumDescription) {
    errors.push({ text: "Please Write a Description" });
  }
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render("forum/", {
      errors,
      forumName,
      forumDescription,
    });
  } else {
    const newForum = new Forum({ forumName, forumDescription });
    newForum.createdBy = users;
    await newForum.save();
    res.status(201).json(newForum);
  }
};
```

How I create a Post

```
###
POST http://localhost:8080/forum/
Authorization: Bearer {Token}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "forumName": "test",
  "forumDescription": "test"
}
```

How I search after

```
exports.get = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { userID } = req.body;
  try {
      const forum = await Forum.findById(userID);
      res.status(200).json(forum);
  } catch (error) {
      error.status = 400;
      next(error);
  }
};
```

The problem is I know userID is wrong I don´t know how to solve it

Comment: are you using JWT or is it just a plain token?

Comment: I´m using JWT yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
let reqToken = req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer' ? return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1] : '';

if(reqToken)
    console.log(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]) // will print your header token 
else 
    return res.status(400).send('Unauthorized');
```

Better way would be to wrap inside a function and handle based on return value.

Comment: But that’s not the answer I search for I can create normally it works I only want to search for the owner of this forum. Only thing is that I don’t have an attribute ownerID in my Model